# How to PHPDoc inline JavaScript string parameter to allow syntax highlight in PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm, phpdoc

WordPress has a PHP function which allows to inject inline JavaScript to the page: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_add_inline_script/

Is there a way to mark the `$data` parameter to tell the IDE that it is a string which contains JavaScript code and then syntax highlight it?

```
wp_add_inline_script( 'xyz', 'new xyz();' );


/**
 * Adds extra code to a registered script.
 *
 * @param string $handle   Name of the script to add the inline script to.
 * @param string $data     String containing the javascript to be added.
 * @param string $position Optional. Whether to add the inline script before the handle
 *                         or after. Default 'after'.
 * @return bool True on success, false on failure.
 */
function wp_add_inline_script( $handle, $data, $position = 'after' ) {
    _wp_scripts_maybe_doing_it_wrong( __FUNCTION__ );

    if ( false !== stripos( $data, '</script>' ) ) {
        _doing_it_wrong( __FUNCTION__, sprintf(
            /* translators: 1: <script>, 2: wp_add_inline_script() */
            __( 'Do not pass %1$s tags to %2$s.' ),
            '<code>&lt;script&gt;</code>',
            '<code>wp_add_inline_script()</code>'
        ), '4.5.0' );
        $data = trim( preg_replace( '#<script[^>]*>(.*)</script>#is', '$1', $data ) );
    }

    return wp_scripts()->add_inline_script( $handle, $data, $position );
}
```

Comment: It highlighted it for me: https://i.gyazo.com/9898fa40e3d88a3ff7f54886141e10fd.png. You can try to add `/** @lang javascript */` annotation to force syntax highlighting there, e.g. `$data = trim( /**@lang javascript */preg_replace( '#<script[^>]*>(.*)</script>#is', '$1', $data ) );`

Comment: @Ástþór It does nothing for me, see: https://i.imgur.com/qTOjEeK.png

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the [Using Language Injections](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/using-language-injections.html) documentation page.

Basically, there are three ways to do this:

1. Put your cursor anyone within your string containing JS, hit `Alt+Enter` (or click the lightbulb), select `Inject language or reference` then pick JS.
2. Define a variable and add `// language=JavaScript` on top of it, then pass it to the method:

   ```
   // language=JavaScript
   $data = 'document.getElementbyId("selector")';

   wp_add_inline_script('handle', $data, 'position');
   ```
3. Probably the most appropriate solution in your case, use `/* language=JavaScript */` before passing your argument:

   ```
   wp_add_inline_script('handle', /* language=JavaScript */ 'document.getElementbyId("selector")', 'position');
   ```

Comment: Thanks, I like the second option. Also is there a way to properly syntax highlight the JavaScript if variables come from PHP? For example: wp_add_inline_script( 'xyz', 'new xyz('. $myPHPVar .');');

Comment: @RolandSoós See my edited answer, third option should be even better.

Comment: yeah, that seems fine, but it does not work if variable comes from PHP, see https://i.imgur.com/J0re2lp.png

Comment: @RolandSoós Try `wp_add_inline_script('xyz', /* language=JavaScript */ "new xyz(\"$myPHPVar\");");` (using string interpolation instead of contatenation).